# PHP: String to actual value

Tags: php

I am creating a function to parse text from a templating system, and add the corresponding values.

For example, the user might input `hi [[first_name]]` and the `[[first_name]]` part will be replaced with the actual first name.

Somehow, I parsed that and ended up with a text that looks like this:

```
hi $info['first_name']
```

The above is just as text though, what can I do to actually make $info['first_name'] be the value (I already have that array in there, but I am not sure how to convert string to PHP variable)

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code where your variables you want inserted into the view are defined.

Comment: Why are you using a templating system *at all*? PHP itself is a templating engine, why add unnecessary overhead on top of it?

Comment: $info['first_name'] is the variable.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ I have been wondering the same thing :) The argument that's it's easier for designers to use `random syntax opening first_name random syntax ending` over `<?= $first_name ?>` doesn't really convince me. ok off-topic but this is killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `str_replace` function:

```
$str = "hi [[first_name]]";
foreach (array_keys($info) as $key) {
    $str = str_replace("[[".$key."]]", $info[$key], $str);
}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 str_replace("[[first_name]]", $info['first_name'], 'hi [[first_name]]');
```

You haven't share your code but you may print the variable name instead of its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myTemplate = "hi [[first_name]], how are you this fine [[day_of_week]]?";

$myData = array(
  '[[first_name]]' => 'James'
  ,'[[day_of_week]]' => 'Friday'
);

echo str_replace(array_keys($myData), array_values($myData), $myTemplate);
?>
```